Require a Typescript abstract class to define properties from another interface that should be defined on parent class
I have a problem I'm trying to solve to get Typescript to ensure that any objects that extend an abstract class, define properties from an interface that's passed in as a generic. Let me try to give you an example:
interface RelationshipData {
   data: {
     id: string;
     type: string;
   }
}

interface Dto<A = Record<string, any>, R = Record<string, RelationshipData>> {
    attributes: A;
    relationships: R;
}

abstract class EntityModel<T extends Dto> {
   // How can I get T['attributes']'s properties and values to be defined on this class?
   // Doing this just errors
   [key in T['attributes']: T['attributes'][key];
}


Here's how the actual implementation would work:
interface ProductAttributes {
   name: string;
   description: string;
}

interface ProductRelationships {
   tenant: RelationshipData;
}

interface ProductDto extends Dto<ProductAttributes, ProductRelationships> {}

export class ProductModel extends EntityModel<ProductDto> {
    /**
     * I want Typescript to error here that I haven't defined the following:
     *
     * name: string;
     * description: string;
     */
}

I've tried the above but it doesn't work.

Please [edit] to make this a [mre] without typos (interface ... =?) or missing declarations (what's BaseEntity? what's Type?). You might want to test it out in an IDE and make sure that the only problems present are the ones you're asking about.

(see prev comment). This is not going to be possible for multiple reasons. One is that class declarations need to have statically known fields, but if the keys of EntityModel<T> depend on T then the fields are not statically known. The other is that there's no way to programmatically make properties abstract. The former can be worked around, the latter cannot. There are undoubtedly refactorings that behave closer to what yout want, but not with an abstract class. If you can [edit] to give a [mre] with declarations for everything (TenantModel is ???) then I can show examples.

@jcalz I've made the edits and removed some unneeded code as just using attributes is what i really want. Let me know if there's anything else I can provide. Thanks for your help!

As I said it cannot be done; in particular you cannot programmatically make things abstract. Instead I suggest you make a factory function that accepts an initializer function and produces the class, possibly as shown in this playground link. Conceptually it's saying that abstract class X { abstract y: string } followed by class SubX extends X { y = "abc" } is similar to a function X that accepts a () => string and then produces a concrete class SubX extends X(()=>({y: "abc"})) {}`. Does that fully address the q? if so I'll write an a, if not, what's missing?

You're stackblitz is perfect and makes more sense now. Go ahead and write the answer and I'll mark it as answered

This is not currently possible in TypeScript. You can't programmatically make abstract properties (that is, you currently need to declare each such property explicitly), and neither classes nor interfaces are allowed to have dynamic keys. There's a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#21326 for this, but it's not part of the language and you need to work around it.

The workaround mentioned inside ms/TS#21326 is to break the abstract class type into the static and dynamic pieces, and add a separate implements clause to force the compiler to check the dynamic part:
abstract class EntityModel<T extends Dto> { }
type DynamicEntityModel<T extends Dto> = T["attributes"]

interface ProductDto extends Dto<ProductAttributes, ProductRelationships> {}

export class ProductModel // error!
  //         ~~~~~~~~~~~~   
  // Class 'ProductModel' incorrectly implements interface 'ProductAttributes'.
  // Type 'EntityModel<ProductDto>' is missing the following properties 
  //   from type 'ProductAttributes': name, description
  extends EntityModel<ProductDto> implements DynamicEntityModel<ProductDto> { 
}


Another approach is to write EntityModel as a class factory function that requires callers pass in a way to initialize the dynamic part of the model, and it will produce the non-abstract class for you:
abstract class StaticEntityModel { }
type DynamicEntityModel<T extends Dto> = T["attributes"]
type EntityModel<T extends Dto> = StaticEntityModel & DynamicEntityModel<T>

function EntityModel<T extends Dto>(
  addedBits: () => DynamicEntityModel<T>
) {
  return class extends StaticEntityModel {
    constructor() {
      super();
      Object.assign(this, addedBits())
    }
  } as new () => EntityModel<T>
}

function productDtoInitializer(): DynamicEntityModel<ProductDto> {
  return {
    description: "abc",
    name: "xyz"
  }
}

export class ProductModel extends EntityModel(productDtoInitializer) {

}

The factory function requires a type assertion since TypeScript can't verify that the initialization has actually occurred.
Playground link to code
